# Como colocar e reproduzir um Arquivo M3u8

Tags: javascript, vídeo, html, stream-de-arquivos

Preciso adicionar este arquivo  (http://tvipbr.net:25461/live/maisiptv21/12345/7106.m3u8)

E Reproduzi-lo de modo que fique mais o menos assim /

https://http2.mlstatic.com/script-google-drive-jw-player-mp4-D_NQ_NP_616907-MLB26843004644_022018-F.jpg

Comment: OIá você precisa ser mais claro com sua pergunta, edite-a para que as  pessoas compreendam   o  que você precisa e se tiver algum código já  pronto publique-o na  pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Esse arquivo é parte de um pacote MPEG-DASH. Vários players de mercado reproduzem isso, mas você precisa do arquivo manifesto pra isso, bem como de todas as partes que para um vídeo de 2 minutos pode ser mais de 200 arquivos.
Geralmente esse arquivo é fornecido criptografado e o browser obtêm a chave de descriptografia (DRM) e trabalha de forma confiável com o servidor.

Se os arquivos estiverem criptografados, é praticamente impossível reproduzir sem a chave que é fornecida dinamicamente durante a reprodução com o player do fornecedor dos dados.

Um exemplo de quem usa isso é Netflix.

Essa é uma empresa que trabalha com esse tipo de player
https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-drm-test-player/

Mais info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management

Comment: Muito obrigado explaceu minha duvida